# "Cannot index number with string" while filtering array

Tags: json, jq

I have a json file (Spanish electricity prices for a given day) where I want to extract in plain text just the *value* for a given *geo_name*: "Península"

The file is as follows:

```
{
  "indicator": {
    "name": "Término de facturación de energía activa del PVPC 2.0TD",
    "short_name": "PVPC T. 2.0TD",
    "id": 1001,
    "composited": false,
    "step_type": "linear",
    "disaggregated": true,
    "magnitud": [
      {
        "name": "Precio",
        "id": 23
      }
    ],
    "tiempo": [
      {
        "name": "Hora",
        "id": 4
      }
    ],
    "geos": [
      {
        "geo_id": 8741,
        "geo_name": "Península"
      },
      {
        "geo_id": 8742,
        "geo_name": "Canarias"
      },
      {
        "geo_id": 8743,
        "geo_name": "Baleares"
      },
      {
        "geo_id": 8744,
        "geo_name": "Ceuta"
      },
      {
        "geo_id": 8745,
        "geo_name": "Melilla"
      }
    ],
    "values_updated_at": "2021-06-01T20:18:22.000+02:00",
    "values": [
      {
        "value": 116.2,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T00:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T22:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T22:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8741,
        "geo_name": "Península"
      },
      {
        "value": 116.2,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T00:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T22:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T22:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8742,
        "geo_name": "Canarias"
      },
      {
        "value": 116.2,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T00:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T22:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T22:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8743,
        "geo_name": "Baleares"
      },
      {
        "value": 116.2,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T00:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T22:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T22:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8744,
        "geo_name": "Ceuta"
      },
      {
        "value": 116.2,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T00:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T22:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T22:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8745,
        "geo_name": "Melilla"
      },
      {
        "value": 114.37,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T01:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T23:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T23:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8741,
        "geo_name": "Península"
      },
      {
        "value": 114.37,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T01:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T23:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T23:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8742,
        "geo_name": "Canarias"
      },
      {
        "value": 114.37,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T01:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T23:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T23:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8743,
        "geo_name": "Baleares"
      },
      {
        "value": 114.37,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T01:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T23:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T23:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8744,
        "geo_name": "Ceuta"
      },
      {
        "value": 114.37,
        "datetime": "2021-06-02T01:00:00.000+02:00",
        "datetime_utc": "2021-06-01T23:00:00Z",
        "tz_time": "2021-06-01T23:00:00.000Z",
        "geo_id": 8745,
        "geo_name": "Melilla"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My "best guess" has been

```
$ jq '.indicator.values[] | .value | select(.indicator.values[] | .geo_name=="Península")' myfile.json
```

But I get a

```
jq: error: Cannot index number with string
```

What can I change to get the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
jq '.indicator.values[] | select(.geo_name=="Península") | .value' myfile.json
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer

What worked for me is:


jq '.indicator.values[] | select(.geo_name=="Península") .value'

Got this from previous answer to my question; unfortunately seems like it has been deleted....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for the answer

What worked for me is:

```
jq '.indicator.values[] | select(.geo_name=="Península") .value'
```

Got this from previous answer to my question; unfortunately seems like it has been deleted....